# django-tables2 sorting non-queryset data

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

Hi I have a table thus:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):

    brand = tables.Column(verbose_name='Brand')
    market = tables.Column(verbose_name='Market')
    date = tables.DateColumn(format='d/m/Y')
    value = tables.Column(verbose_name='Value')
```

I'm populating the table with a [list of dicts](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/table-data.html#populating-a-table-with-data) and then I'm configuring it and rendering it in my view in the usual django-tables2 way:

```
data = [
    {'brand': 'Nike', 'market': 'UK', 'date': <datetime obj>, 'value': 100},
    {'brand': 'Django', 'market': 'FR', 'date': <datetime obj>, 'value': 100},    
]

table = MyTable(data)

RequestConfig(request, paginate=False).configure(table)

context = {'table': table}

return render(request, 'my_tmp.html', context)
```

This all renders the table nicely with the correct data in it. However, I can sort by the `date` column and the `value` column on the webpage, but not by the `brand` and `market`. So it seems non-string values can be sorted but strings can't. I've been trying to figure out how to do this sorting, is it possible with non-queryset data?

I can't populate the table with a queryset, as I'm using custom methods to generate the `value` column data. Any help appreciated! I guess I need to specify the `order_by` parameter in my `tables.Column` but haven't found the correct setting yet.

Answer (score -1):

`data.sort(key = lambda item: item["brand"].lower())` will sort the list in place (so it will return None; the original 'data' list is edited) based on brand (alphabetically). The same can be done for any key.

Alternatively, `sorted(data, key = lambda item: item["brand"].lower())` returns a sorted copy of the list.

Comment: where would I put this piece of code, in the table or the view?

Comment: after you get the information as a list, inser the list into this code :)

Comment: also any idea why the `Column` objects support sorting the datetime objects and non-string values natively, but not strings?

Comment: (where data is the list)

Comment: No, I am not familiar with django

Comment: I know how to sort a list in python... this question is about sorting data in a django-tables2 table when rendered on a webpage

Comment: You can sort the list then render the sorted version I think

Comment: @DrBuck django-tables should be able to sort on string values too. Can you maybe post an issue at https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues if it doesn't sort like you expect?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response @Jieter I made a stupid mistake... I was putting model objects as values for my `brand` and `market` keys so I realise now the table was sorting on the object integer values rather than their evaluated string.